# OrientDB metadata attributes

Tags: python, orientdb, pyorient

I'm trying orientdb with python. I have created a couple of vertices and I noticed that if I prepend their properties name with @, when I search them on the estudio web app, those properties show up in the metadata section.
Thats interesting, so i went and tried to query vertices filtering by a metadata property *id* that i created.
When doing so:

```
select from V where @id = somevalue
```

I get a huge error msg. I couldnt find a way of querying those custom metadata properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with python/pyorient (I am presuming you are using pyorient based upon your other questions).

Pyorient attempts to map the database fields to object attributes, but python docs say `the valid characters for identifiers are the same as in Python 2.x: the uppercase and lowercase letters A through Z, the underscore _ and, except for the first character, the digits 0 through 9.` [(source)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). Thus, you cannot use '@' as a field name and expect pyorient to work.

---

I went and took a quick peek at pyorient source code, and it turns out the problem is even bigger than above...
[pyorient/types.py](https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/blob/master/pyorient/types.py)

```
elif key[0:1] == '@':
    # special case dict
    # { '@my_class': { 'accommodation': 'hotel' } }
    self.__o_class = key[1:]
    for _key, _value in content[key].items():
        self.__o_storage[_key] = _value
```

So pyorient presumes any record field that begins with an '@' character is followed by a class/cluster name, and then a dict of fields. I suppose you could post to the [pyorient issue queue](https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/issues) and suggest that the above elif section should check if `content[key]` is a dict, or a "simple value". If it were a dict, it should be handled like it currently is, otherwise it should be handled like a field, but have the @ stripped from it.

**Ultimately, not using the @ symbol in your field names will be the easiest solution.**